# Class-bound protocol refinement in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

Why does this code throw a compile error?

```
protocol P { var i: Int { get set } }
protocol ClassP: P, AnyObject {}
class C: ClassP { var i: Int = 0 }

let classP: ClassP = C()
classP.i = 1   //  Cannot assign to property: 'classP' is a 'let' constant
```

But all is fine if I move the `AnyObject` restriction to `P`:

```
protocol P: AnyObject { var i: Int { get set } }
protocol ClassP: P {}
class C: ClassP { var i: Int = 0 }

let classP: ClassP = C()
classP.i = 1
```

Note how `classP` is typed as `ClassP`, and `ClassP` is class-bound in both examples. But the compiler seems to notice that the assignment targets the property of a class instance (as opposed to a struct instance) only if the property is declared in a protocol that itself is already class-bound. The static type of `classP` seems to get ignored. Why?

Ideally `P` itself shouldn't be class-bound, as it could easily have non-class-bound refinements and conforming types. Of course in those cases a `p.i = 1` assignment would only be valid with a writeable `p`. With a let-const `p`, `p.i = 1` should only be valid if `p` is known to be an instance of a conforming *class* (which I'd think is true in the above example, because the known type is `ClassP` and that is indeed class-bound). How do I express this in Swift?

Comment: For an explanation, see https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5883.

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty but adding `i` as a requirement of `ClassP` silence the error:

```
protocol P { var i: Int { get set } }
protocol ClassP: P, AnyObject { var i: Int { get set }  }
class C: ClassP { var i: Int = 0 }

let classP: ClassP = C()
classP.i = 1
```